# Integral of $\mathrm{sgn}(f(x))\max(f(x) - a, 0)$ for $a>0$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Title basically says it. I want to calculate $$\int_0^1\mathrm{sgn}(f(x))\cdot\max(f(x) - a, 0)\:\mathrm dx$$ for some $a>0$ and an integrable function $f$. I tried to split of the integral to get rid of the sign function: $$\int_0^1\max(f(x) - a, 0)\cdot\mathsf 1_{\{x:f(x) < 0\}}\:\mathrm dx + \int_0^1\max(f(x) - a,0)\cdot\mathsf 1_{\{x:f(x) > 0\}}\:\mathrm dx.$$
Since $a>0$, I know that the first integral has to be zero as $f(x) - a$ is certainly smaller than zero. For the second part I could deduce that $$\int_0^1(f(x) - a)\cdot\mathsf 1_{\{x:f(x) > a\}}\:\mathrm dx.$$ But what does that mean? How can I solve this integral (provided my previous steps were correct)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geometrically, the integral represents the following:

[image]

Evaluating the integral will depend on what $f$ is. I don't think there's a general way to evaluate such an integral for arbitrary $f$.